# Execute Bash one-liner with different quotes from Java code for Elasticsearch query

Tags: java, bash, unix, elasticsearch

Im trying to execute a Elastic search post query inside my java code. i want the code to be executed on my machine using the bash shell.

Here is my code:

```
public class Elastic {
public static void main(String[] args) {

String cmd = "curl -X PUT IP:PORT/twitter/_doc/10 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ \"user\" : \"Bob\", \"post_date\" : \"2019-12-15T14:12:10\", \"message\" : \"trying out Elasticsearch\" }' ";


   try {
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

/*
   try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash "+"-c "+"\'"+cmd+"\'");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }   */
System.out.println("===============");
System.out.println(cmd);
 }
 }
```

Ive tried to to it in two different ways, as you can see from the code that has been commented out.

I print the query i constructed in order to verify it. When i execute this program on my local machine and try the printed query in the terminal, it works, but not in my java code/bash query. I guess it has something to do with the formatting and the use of single quotation marks, but i have not yet been able to run it directly from my code.

Comment: Strongly suggesting to use [Apache Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/) or another Java HTTP library instead of running CURL over the IPC. You are making you Java program less portable by executing 3-D party processes from the code. At least you would need to modify your code for UNIX(Linux,FreeBSD,MacOS X) and Windows when running CURL.

Comment: I edited your headline so your question can be found better by people with similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to write the script in a separate file and then use

```
String[] cmdScript = new String[]{"/bin/bash", "path/to/myScript.sh"}; 
Process procScript = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdScript);
```

If you also want to add parameters you could use something like

```
Process procBuildScript = new ProcessBuilder("path/to/myScript.sh", "myArg1 myArg2").start();
```

Comment: Also good idea to await unless child process [ends](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--). And then check the [exit code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue--)

Comment: @CobraKai Glad I could help. Since your problem was solved, please mark the answer as accepted. This will make the post appear as answered and may help other people with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Best approach**

Please see the other answers for suggestions on an altogether better approach.

**How to fix this approach**

This is the correct (and tricky) quoting for your current approach:

```
String cmd = "curl -X PUT IP:PORT/twitter/_doc/10 -H '"\'"'Content-Type: application/json'"\'"' -d '"\'"'{ \"user\" : \"Bob\", \"post_date\" : \"2019-12-15T14:12:10\", \"message\" : \"trying out Elasticsearch\" }'"\'"' ";

[...]

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash "+"-c "+"'"+cmd+"'");
```

Inside the string passed to the shell inside single quotes, you escape other single quotes by ending the current single quote (`'`), starting a double quote (`"`), adding an escaped single quote (`\'`), closing the double quote (`"`) and continuing the single-quoted string (`'`).

Put together, we write this as `'"\'"'`, with context it is `bli '"\'"'single-quote-inside-json'"\'"' bla`, which becomes `/bin/bash -c 'bli '"\'"'single-quote-inside-json'"\'"' bla'`.

**Why so complicated?**

The reason why this is necessary can be found in the bash(1) manual page:

> A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

That's why we must end the single quote, start a double quote (where the single quote can be escaped), end the double quote, and continue our single quote again.

Comment: Thanks dude. Used one of the previous suggested methods to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Separating arguments and quoting correctly can be tricky to get right using only `Runtime.exec`.

I'd recommend you have a look at the more robust [ProcessBuilder API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) if you need to pass complex arguments like json.